# Use of "notify"

Tags: grammaticality

Do you feel this usage of *notify* is OK?

> The company will notify Mr Bloggs to the New York Stock Exchange as an independent officer according to its regulations.

Comment: It's possible that it's considered normal jargon for the Stock Exchange.  It's not "proper" English, however.

Comment: It depends if Bloggs is operating as an agent or representative of the company, or they're just providing a recommendation to the NYSE that Bloggs (someone they have no legal relationship with) is someone they might like to appoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what is meant.

In your sentence, is Mr. Bloggs being sent as a representative from the company to the Stock Exchange according to the Stock Exchange's regulations? If so, the sentence should be "The company will notify the New York Stock Exchange that Mr Bloggs has been named as an independent officer according to its regulations."